# Using Modules in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, module

I am writing a program that contains three forms and a module. One form has two listboxes, one for the items for sale and one for the items purchased, there is also a textbox for the user to enter the quantity they would like of each item, and a button to calculate the total price. The items for sale and their prices are listed below:

Wheat Bread- $1.15
White Bread- $1.05
Donuts- $0.50 and 8.3% sales tax
Raisins- $0.25 and 2.0% sales tax

Like I said, there are 2 other forms besides this one, but once I understand how to work with this one, the others won't be a problem.

The module is supposed to be used to keep record of all taxes and is used to do all tax-related functions.

The problem is, I've never worked with modules before and am not sure how to set it up and then cal it from my other forms. Here is the code I have written so far for the first form,

```
Option Strict On
Public Class Form1

Dim total As Double = 0
Dim Quantity As Integer

Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    If (txtQuantity.Text = "") Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a quantity for the item you selected")
    ElseIf Not Integer.TryParse(txtQuantity.Text, Quantity) Then
        MessageBox.Show("The quantity entered is not numeric. Please add a numeric quantity.")
        Exit Sub
    Else
        lstPurchased.Items.Add(txtQuantity.Text & " " & lstSale.Text)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
    lstPurchased.Items.Clear()
    txtQuantity.Clear()
End Sub

Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
    For Each item In lstSale.SelectedItems
        Select Case CStr(item)
            Case ("Wheat Bread")
                total += (CDbl(FormatCurrency(txtQuantity.Text)) * 1.15)
            Case ("White Bread")
                total += (CDbl(FormatCurrency(txtQuantity.Text)) * 1.05)
            Case ("Donuts")
                total += (CDbl(FormatCurrency(CDbl(txtQuantity.Text) * 0.5 * DONUT_TAX)))
            Case ("Raisins")
                total += (CDbl(FormatCurrency(CDbl(txtQuantity.Text) * (0.25 * RAISIN_TAX) + 0.25)))
        End Select
    Next
    MessageBox.Show(CStr(total))
 End Sub
End Class
```

Here is what little I have for the module, like I said, I've never had to use modules before so am not sure how to set it up.

```
Module TaxesModule
Public Const DONUT_TAX As Decimal = 0.083
Public Const RAISIN_TAX As Decimal = 0.02
Public Const SS_TAX As Decimal = 0.062

Public Function SalesTax(ByVal 

End Module
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for your calculate button click action, you have to go to every selected item. like this:

```
Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
        Dim total As Double = 0

        'summarize all selected items
        For Each item In lstSale.SelectedItems
            Select Case CStr(item)
                Case ("Wheat Bread")
                    total += (CDbl(FormatCurrency(txtQuantity.Text)) * 1.15)
                Case ("White Bread")
                    total += (CDbl(FormatCurrency(txtQuantity.Text)) * 1.05)
                Case ("Donuts")
                    total += (CDbl(FormatCurrency(CDbl(txtQuantity.Text) * 0.5 * DONUT_TAX)))
                Case ("Raisins")
                    total += (CDbl(FormatCurrency(CDbl(txtQuantity.Text) * (0.25 * RAISIN_TAX) + 0.25)))
            End Select
        Next
        MessageBox.Show(CStr(total))
    End Sub
```

All Variables, Functions ect. are accessible from every where in your code, without creating a instance of it. so, you can keep your taxes in the module.

access the module:

```
Public Class MyClass1
    Private Sub DoSomething()
        TOTAL += Add(40, 30)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class MyClass2
    Private Sub DoSomething()
        TOTAL += Add(10, 20)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Module MyModule1
    Public TOTAL As Integer = 0
    Public Function Add(ByVal firstValue As Integer, ByVal secondValue As Integer) As Integer
        Return firstValue + secondValue
    End Function
End Module
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it is still not incrementing total correctly. Also I'm still pretty confused on the module, like how would I set up my taxes within the module?

Comment: Got total to increment correctly thanks to a combination of this answer and the other answer, still stuck on the module though.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare total in class level, not in the eventhandler ...

```
Option Strict On
Public Class Form1
Dim total As Double = 0 '<---- put it here

....
....

End Class
```